# Autofac register with folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I use Autofac. I have a lot of classes here and I have to add each one individually. Besides, all my classes are not in a single file. Can I directly save the classes in that file by giving the file path?

```
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


        builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.MailController>().SingleInstance();
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
        builder.RegisterType<Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete.CacheCategory>().SingleInstance();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Can you help with the "CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.MailController" and "Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete.CacheCategory" classes in the example?

So I write over and over again to register each class.

```
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.AController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.BController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.CController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.DController>().SingleInstance();
```

Can we register instead by giving a direct file path?

builder.RegisterType<***CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.*.cs***>().SingleInstance();

I want this because I have too many class. All of them are in different files.

CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods
|->AController,BController,CController,DController,EController,FController,....
Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete
|->XController,YController,ZController,....

and I write each one to register them.

```
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.AController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.AController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.AController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.AController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.AController>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete.XController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete.YController>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete.ZController>().SingleInstance();
```

Can we register the controllers for the file instead?

example:

```
 builder.RegisterType<CommonBusinessLayer.MyCommonMethods.*.cs>().SingleInstance();
 builder.RegisterType<Mvc.MyMethods.Concrete.*.cs>().SingleInstance();
```

Ben denedim, böyle;

```
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
           .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Repository"))
           .SingleInstance();

    //builder.RegisterType<RepositoryUser>().SingleInstance();
    //builder.RegisterType<RepositoryCategory>().SingleInstance();
    //builder.RegisterType<RepositoryProvince>().SingleInstance();
    //..........
    //builder.RegisterType<RepositoryDistrict>().SingleInstance();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

and result;

None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Mvc.Controllers.KonumController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'CommonBusinessLayer.Repository.RepositoryDistrict repoDistrict' of constructor 'Void .ctor(CommonBusinessLayer.Repository.RepositoryDistrict, CommonBusinessLayer.Repository.RepositoryUser)'.

Comment: You should start using the [MVC integration for Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html). It contains a `RegisterControllers` method that does Auto-Registration of all MVC controllers.

Comment: Also take a look at the concept of [assembly scanning](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html). This would solve your second quest.

Comment: i was try it and result;

None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Mvc.Controllers.KonumController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its work.

My repository is inheriting from repositoryBase. With the help of RepositoryBase, I introduced the file path and recorded what started with Repository in it.

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(RepositoryBase))).Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Repository")).SingleInstance();
```